# Constantly reading files in a directory with c# windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm looking for a good solution to constantly read files within a directory in my windows service. Currently, I'm using FileSystemWatcher to process xml files that get added to the directory.This works well when the service is running. However, if the services gets stopped for whatever reason, the files that were added to the directory while the service was stopped never get processed. What's the best possible solution? Below is the code I have for FileSystemWatcher. Maybe FileSystemWatcher can do this, however, I could be using it incorrectly.

```
// Setup FileSystemWatcher to watch 'IN' directory...
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InputPath"];
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
watcher.Filter = "*.xml";
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName;
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileAdded);
```

Comment: You should also be aware that FileSystemWatcher may not be able to keep up if there are lots of changes. Please see Remarks section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Thank you for the heads up. I will take a look at that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're stating two different use cases - startup and monitoring.
The FileSystemWatcher is simply for monitoring.

But on startup, you have to look into the filesystem itself, see if there are any files waiting, and if so, deal with them.  Ideally, you should be able to use your FileAdded function, or at least have FileAdded call the same function to process the file.

On startup, I would do a simple loop:
    while (there are any files in InputPath)
    {
        process a file();
    }
    add the FileSystemEventHandler code;

Comment: Wow...You're solution is so simple that it may work. I guess I was over complicating things. During startup, I will read the directory before watching. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks.  Now for the bonus question - do you have to worry about the service going down after you've processed a file but before you deleted it?  In the past, I worked around it by having a temp file that simply stated what file I was working on.  Write to that file before beginning processing, and don't delete it until after you've deleted the file in the queue.  Add some extra checks on startup to see if that file exists, and what state your work-in-progress file is in.

Answer (score 0):

`FileSystemWatcher` will only give you visibility on current changes to files while it is active.  To catch changes while it is not, you'll have to track them in a separate, persistent (external file, DB) list.  Upon waking, your process will have to check the files in the directory against your list to see if any are new.

Other caveats: if your system is watching a directory that is being written from possibly slow connections (e.g., watching an FTP directory) you'll need to set up another watcher or other mechanism that checks that the file isn't still changing for a period after it was added.

Also as noted elsewhere, careful your directory isn't too busy or you'll miss updates.